# PHP How to limit users to a specific number of files that can be uploaded

Tags: php, file, pdo

I've been searching for ways to limit users to "5" file uploads and if they upload more, echo a message. I want to limit 5 because just in case of spammers and users that want to cheat the system and upload more than 5 into he database.
 [I found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23934012/7710352)

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'][5])){
  // Code

}else{

  //exit
}
```

But, it's not working for me. It still sends to the database and skips the, if file is greater than 5, checker. Here is my code

PHP

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =="POST"){


         if(!empty($_POST['price']) && !empty($_POST['description'])){

             if(!ctype_digit($_POST['price'])){

            echo "PRICE ENTERED IS NOT AN INTEGER... PLEASE TRY AGAIN!";
            exit;
        }
            $price = addslashes(trim((int)$_POST['price']));
            $description = addslashes(trim($_POST['description']));
            if(strlen($description) < 15){

                echo "Description field needs to be GREATER than 15 characters!";
                exit;
            }

             if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'][5])){


                 try{

                    // new php data object 
                    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=magicsever', 'root', '');
                    //ATTR_ERRMODE set to exception
                    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                }catch(PDOException $e){
                     die("There was an error connecting to the database");   

                }

                 $query = "INSERT INTO test(name, file)VALUES(:file_name, :file_tmp)";
                 $stmt = $handler->prepare($query);
                 $errors = array();

                 foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error){

                     if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                        $errors[] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key] . ' was not uploaded.';
                        continue;
                    }

                     $file_name = $key.$_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
                     $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];

                     try{

                         $stmt->bindParam(':file_name', $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                         $stmt->bindParam(':file_tmp', $file_tmp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                         $stmt->execute();

                         $dir = "devFiles";

                         if(is_dir($dir)==false){

                             mkdir($dir, 0700);
                         }

                         if(is_file($dir.'/'.$file_name)==false){

                             move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$dir.'/'.$file_name);

                         }else{

                            echo '<br><h1 style="color:red;">VALUES MISSING!</h1>';
                            exit;
                         }
                     }catch(PDOException $e){

                         $errors[] = $file_name . 'not saved in db.';
                         echo $e->getMessage();
                     }
                 }

                 echo "pk";
             }else{

                echo "tooo big";
                 exit;
             }

             }else{

             echo '<br><h1 style="color:red;">VALUES MISSING!</h1>';
             exit;

     }



         }
```

Comment: *"But, it's not working for me."* - Can you elaborate on that? any errors? where's the HTML/form for this?

Comment: You are already looping over the files with `foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error){` why not introduce a counter and `break` on the fifth?

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- i updated it

Comment: @colburton do i just set the counter to 0 before the "foreach" part and check if its 5 in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is currently checking for the existence of a 6th file and continuing.  Instead:

```
if (count($_FILES['file']['name']) <= 5) {
    ...
```

Comment: I think you got that because of how you explained it.

Comment: Ohhhh thanks that worked perfectly :D And do you think my code is less likely to get "hacked" because i am using the PDO?

Comment: Prepared statements are the safest way to write SQL. You might also want to validate file names since you're using that to generate a path on disk. There's a lot to file upload security that you'll find online.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing the code if there ARE more than 5, you want to check that there are NOT more than 5 so use `!`:

```
if(!isset($_FILES['file']['name'][5])){
```

But you could probably just count:

```
if(count($_FILES['file']['name']) < 6){
```